# GUI interaction with terminal

Tags: python, pyqt5, interactive, python-3.8

**Is it possible to set up a Python script with a PyQt5 GUI such that an active terminal can interact with it?**

An example project:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot


class Machine:
    """Simpel state machine"""

    STATE_IDLE = 'idle'
    STATE_OPERATION = 'operation'

    def __init__(self):

        self.state = self.STATE_IDLE

    def get_state(self):
        return self.state

    def set_state(self, new_state):
        self.state = new_state


@pyqtSlot() def on_click():
    """Callback for the PyQt button"""
    print('State:', machine.get_state())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create machine instance
    machine = Machine()

    # Set up GUI

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello World!')
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Go')
    button.clicked.connect(on_click)
    layout.addWidget(label)
    layout.addWidget(button)
    window.setLayout(layout)
    window.show()

    code = app.exec()

    exit(code)
```

I would like to run this script and to then be able to access the objects from the same terminal. Something like:

```
$ python main.py

State: idle   [< I just pressed the GUI button]

>> machine.set_state(Machine.STATE_OPERATION)
  
State: operation   [< I just pressed the GUI button again]
```

If I run it like:

```
python -i main.py
```

The command line hangs until the application was closed (that's what `.exec()` does after all), but then I can access `machine`. Can I make `.exec()` not hang like this? Maybe run app from a separate thread?

**EDIT:** I found that thy Pyzo IDE allows you to create a shell with PyQt5 support, which handles the PyQt event loop. So when using the script above with such a Pyzo shell, I can remove `code = app.exec()    exit(code)` because Pyzo will run the event loop and keep the window alive. Now I'd like to do the same across all IDEs.

Comment: then remove `code = app.exec()

    exit(code)`

Comment: Then the GUI is instantly closed

Comment: then only remove `exit(code)`

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. As I've said, the code hangs on `exec()` itself.